# Selenium web driver: DevTools request failed- when try to open the chrome driver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When i try to open the chrome browser through selenium web driver, Sometime it is not opening and i am getting following error log.
It is happening randomly not for all the time and i have used latest version of selenium web driver and chrome driver which is suit for latest selenium version.

```
[0.685][INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-automation --enable-logging --force-fieldtrials=SiteIsolationExtensions/Control --ignore-certificate-errors --load-component-extension="C:\Users\T002812\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir8344_11442\internal" --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12855 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\T002812\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir8344_1252" data:,
[0.733][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[2.839][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[2.889][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[3.031][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[3.081][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[4.894][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[4.944][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[5.084][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[5.134][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[6.952][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[7.002][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[7.143][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[7.193][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[9.007][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[9.057][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[9.199][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[9.249][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[11.062][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[11.113][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[11.254][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[11.305][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[13.116][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[13.167][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[13.308][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[13.359][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[15.167][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[15.218][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[15.359][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[15.410][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[17.214][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[17.264][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[17.413][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[17.464][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12855/json/version
[19.268][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed

[62.397][INFO]: RESPONSE InitSession chrome not reachable
[62.397][DEBUG]: Log type 'driver' lost 0 entries on destruction
[62.397][DEBUG]: Log type 'browser' lost 0 entries on destruction
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score -1):

The cause may be in Chrome privacy protection by proxy.
To disable it please see: https://www.expressvpn.com/support/troubleshooting/google-chrome-no-proxy/

Comment: How to disable this proxy when running chrome headless? And what if you need a proxy to access the outside world?